# How to implement negative indexes in java?

Tags: java, arrays

In Python, you are allowed to use negative array indices to count starting from the right side of an array. For example, `array[-1]` is last element and `array[-2]` is the second last element in the array. How would you implement this in Java?

Comment: It is now easier to understand what is being asked. Could someone reopen this question please?

Comment: Of course you can create your own object. But it will have a methods like PythonArray.getElement( int elementIndex)

Comment: A one-liner to accept positive and negative indices would be something like this: `i >= 0 ? array[i] : array[array.length+i];` You may add it to as a static method to your Utils class and just call that method, like `Util.getElementAt(array, i);`, instead of `array[i]`.

Comment: You can simulate it like so: `int idx = (array.length + negIdx) % array.length;`

Comment: I posted an answer with an example code regarding negative array indexes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70872912/6761506). Unfortunately, this question is closed, so I cannot leave it here, but I believe it answers the question nicely.

Answer (score 37):

Java does not support negative indexes, to access the last cell, you should use

```
array[array.length-1] = lastElement;
```

Comment: If you have an index `idx` and don't know if it will be positive or negative, you can do the following;: `array[(array.length+idx)%array.length] = oneElement;`

Answer (score 5):

To implement something like this, you would have to create a circular, doubly linked list...
*I did not compile and test this, but this is the general idea...*

```
public class LinkedList {
    Integer node;
    LinkedList next;
    LinkedList prev;
    public LinkList(Integer node) {
        this.node = node;
        this.next = this;
        this.prev = this;
    }
    public void insert(Integer node) {
        if(this.node == null) {
            this.node = node;
            this.next = this;
            this.prev = this;
        }
        else if(this.next == null) {
            this.next = new LinkedList(node);
            this.prev = node
            this.next.prev = this;
            this.next.next = this;
        }
        else {
            this.next(node, this);
        }
    }
    private void insert(Integer node, LinkedList head) {
        if(this.next == null) {
            this.next = new LinkedList(node);
            this.next.prev = this;
            this.next.next = head;
        }
        else {
            this.next(node, head);
        }
    }
    public Interger get(int index) {
        int cursor = 0;
        if(index == cursor) {
            return this.node;
        }
        else if(index < cursor) {
            return this.prev.get(index, cursor-1);
        }
        else {
            return this.next.get(index, cursor+1);
        }
    }
    private Interger get(int index, int cursor) {
        if(index == cursor) {
            return this.node;
        }
        else if(index < cursor) {
            return this.prev.get(index, cursor-1);
        }
        else {
            return this.next.get(index, cursor+1);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(new Integer(1));
    list.insert(new Integer(2));
    list.insert(new Integer(3));
    System.out.println(list.get(-1).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Java subscript index starts with 0.  No negative index can be used. If at all used then java will throw Array Index out of bounds Exception.