# JAVA how to implement wraparound on a deque

Tags: java, queue, deque

I am trying to implement wraparound on my double ended queue and for some reason my insertRight() and removeRight() methods are outputting wrong and my removeLeft() method is just throwing an error. I have looked around and I cannot seem to find an answer to why my methods are not working here they are:

```
public void insertRight(int newItem) {
    if (isFull() == true) {
        System.out.print("Full");
    } // end of if
    else {
        if (right == capacity) {
            right = 0;
        } // end of nested if
        else {
            deque[right] = newItem;
            nElems++;
            right++;
        } // end of nested else
    } // end of else
}// end of insertRight

public void removeRight() {

    if (isEmpty() == true) {
        System.out.println("Empty");
    } // end of if
    if (isEmpty() == false) {
        System.out.println(right);
        if (right == capacity) {
            right = 0;
        } // end of nested if
        int temp = deque[right];
        right++;
        nElems--;
    } // end of if
}// end of removeRight

public void removeLeft() {
    if (isEmpty() == true) {
        System.out.println("Empty");
    } // end of if
    if (isEmpty() == false) {
        if (left == capacity) {
            left = -1;
        } // end of nested if
        else {
            System.out.println(left);
            int temp = deque[left];
            left++;
            nElems--;
        } // end of else
    } // end of if
}// end of removeLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more information on the actual meaning/values of `left` and `right` would be helpful.

At first glance, it looks like `removeLeft()` fails because the wrap-around point for `left` would be 0, not `capacity`, if my understanding of your code so far is correct.

Also, [negative array indices do not work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000088/how-to-implement-negative-indexes-in-java). You'll want to refer to the actual last index directly.

And I really recommend looking into code formatting. Your indentation makes it very hard to tell where one block ends and a new one begins. You could save yourself explicit comments by just following a consistent indentation pattern:

```
public void insertRight(int newItem) {
    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.print("Full");
    } else {
        if (right == capacity) {
            right = 0;
        } else {
            deque[right] = newItem;
            nElems++;
            right++;
        }
    }
}


public void removeRight() {

    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Empty");
    } else {
        System.out.println(right);
        if (right == capacity) {
            right = 0;
        }
        int temp = deque[right];
        right++;
        nElems--;
    }
}


public void removeLeft() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Empty");
    } else {
        // My assumption inserted here:
        if (left == 0) {
            left = capacity - 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println(left);
            int temp = deque[left];
            left++;
            nElems--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues here:

```
    if (right == capacity) {
        right = 0;
    } // end of nested if
    else {
        deque[right] = newItem;
        nElems++;
        right++;
    } // end of nested else
```

If `right == capacity` you reset the index but don't insert `newItem` to the array.

It should be something like this (directly typed, not tested):

```
    if (right == capacity) {
        right = 0;
    } // end of nested if
    deque[right] = newItem;
    nElems++;
    right++;
```

Now to your `removeRight`-method:

```
    System.out.println(right);
    if (right == capacity) {
        right = 0;
    } // end of nested if
    int temp = deque[right];
    right++;
    nElems--;
```

Here you use the same algorithm to check boundaries but it should be a "mirror" to the one you used in `insertRight`, so something like this (directly typed, not tested):

```
    System.out.println(right);
    if (right == 0) {
        right = capacity;
    } // end of nested if
    int temp = deque[right - 1];
    right--;
    nElems--;
```

And finally `removeLeft`:

```
    if (left == capacity) {
        left = -1;
    } // end of nested if
    else {
        System.out.println(left);
        int temp = deque[left];
        left++;
        nElems--;
    } // end of else
```

Without the `insertLeft` method, I can only guess that it has similar problems.

Comment: I tried your method Lothar and I am still having a problem with it outputting wrong, When I insert 1, 2 , 3 into insertLeft() and I try to remove all three with removeRight() the output is 3 2 3.