# Can array's index be negative number in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[10];
    a[1] =2;
    a[-1] = -2;
    a[0] = 0;
    System.out.println(a[-1]);

}
```

I write codes above, editor didn't judge it illegal, but when I run it, it give me 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"

So is negative number index in java is illegal all the time? Or there's some special situation can let array's index be negative number?

Comment: no. Java arrays cannot have negative indexes

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` then

Comment: The editor is just a helper, not the judge. The compiler is the judge :)

Comment: Eight answers, so far, saying the same thing. How many ways are there to say No?

Comment: No, negative index is not possible but your problem can be solve if you tell exact issues that why you need this.

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a look at Oracle's documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html). This is what it says:

> An array object contains a number of variables. The number of variables may be zero, in which case the array is said to be empty. The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that use **non-negative** integer index values. These variables are called the components of the array. If an array has n components, we say n is the length of the array; the components of the array are referenced using integer indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive.

Also,

> All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index
>   that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the
>   array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown.

To answer the question, no, index can't be negative.

Answer (score 4):

There is no support in java for negative indices.
Last element can be accessed using

```
array[array.length-1] = lastElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

> So is negative number index in java is illegal all the time?

Yes.

> Or there's some special situation can let array's index be a negative number?

You could write own array-like collection type where negative indices would be valid. It would be rather a domain-specific type because I can't think of any general applications.

A simple example would be

```
// define an anonymous class that overrides ArrayList's get behaviour
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
    @Override
    public String get(int index) {
        return super.get(Math.abs(index));
    }
};

list.add("a");
list.add("b");

System.out.println(list.get(-1)); // b
System.out.println(list.get(1));  // b
```

It's not what I would recommend you do. It's confusing and unusual for any Java developer.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, they cannot be negative.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get-java.lang.Object-int-)(using `get` for example)

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - If the specified index argument is negative, or if it is greater than or equal to the length of the specified array

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Slightly less short answer: Array indices range from 0 to the length of the array minus 1.

E.g. :

```
int[] ints = new int[5];
ints[0] = 1;  // fine
ints[4] = 1;  // fine
ints[-1] = 1;  // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown
ints[5] = 1;  // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown
```

Comment: most of comments and answeres point to the same thing that you can't directly access a negative index and you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsEcception , but since negative index means walking in the array with reverse order I suggest accepting the answer provided by @Diya as the solution

Answer (score 0):

In java, Negative index can't  be used. It is 0 based positive index. If used negative index then java will throw `"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"` Exception.

Answer (score 0):

arrays in java can not be indexed using negative numbers, the "problem" is that there is no such unsigned integers defined until now in java, so writing myArr[x] will compile as soon a x is a valid numerical index

Answer (score 0):

As @Darshan Mehta's answer says, negative numbers are not allowed as array indexes. However, you can always write your own array class that allows negative indices.

Here's my example using generics.

```
public class ModuloArray<E> {
    int size;
    E[] array;

    public ModuloArray(int size) {
        if (size <= 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("not positive");
        
        this.size = size;
        array = (E[]) new Object[size];
    }
    
    public ModuloArray(E... elements) {
        if (elements == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("null");
        
        this.size = elements.length;
        array = elements;
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        return array[Math.floorMod(index, size)];
    }
    
    public void set(int index, E element) {
        array[Math.floorMod(index, size)] = element;
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*** ModuloArray with first constructor ***");
        ModuloArray<String> myArray = new ModuloArray<>(3);
        myArray.set(-1, "apple");
        myArray.set(-2, "orange");
        myArray.set(-3, "banana");
        
        System.out.println(myArray.get(-3));
        System.out.println(myArray.get(-2));
        System.out.println(myArray.get(-1));
        System.out.println(myArray.get(0));
        System.out.println(myArray.get(1));
        System.out.println(myArray.get(2));
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*** ModuloArray with second constructor ***");
        ModuloArray<String> myArray2 = new ModuloArray<>("glazed donut", "chicken burger", "apple soda");
        
        System.out.println(myArray2.get(-2));
        System.out.println(myArray2.get(3));
    }
}
```

The above example outputs:

```
*** ModuloArray with first constructor ***
banana
orange
apple
banana
orange
apple

*** ModuloArray with second constructor ***
chicken burger
glazed donut
```

Array indexes in Java are valid only if `0 <= index < array.length` is true. However, because `ModuloArray` uses [`Math.floorMod(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) to access the array elements, any integer *(including negative numbers)* can be used as a valid index. This behavior is similar to how indexing works for lists in Python.
[image]